# Saving/Loading a GameObject with Texture on Unity3D with Unity Serializer

Tags: serialization, unity-game-engine

I am trying to save a single game object (although I want the game object to contain children as well) downloaded from the web. First I do this

```
var s = JSONLevelSerializer.SaveObjectTree( obj );
PlayerPrefs.SetString( "test", s );
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

to save. And later (the next time I click play)

```
JSONLevelSerializer.LoadObjectTree (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("test"));
```

It indeed loads back the game object but

1. with the render turned off
2. without the original texture

**How can I save/load game objects with texture?**